# Matching multiple properties in mapbox gl js filter

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to write a filter that will match on values from several properties of a layer.

For example, in my hypothetical layer of breweries, I'd like to match those breweries that have a state name of Utah, Texas or Florida and a brewery type of Irish or American.

I can filter on state like this

```
var stateFilter = ['match', ['get', 'stateNam'], ['Utah','Texas','Florida'], true, false]
map.setFilter('breweriesLayer',stateFilter)
```

Or on brewery type like this

```
var typeFilter = ['match', ['get', 'breweryType'], ['Irish','American'], true, false]
map.setFilter('breweriesLayer',typeFilter)
```

How can I combine the two examples above into one filter? I looked at using expressions and concatenation of fields but in my actual use case, I have several fields with 100s of possible values, making the expressions cumbersome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like I had some of my expressions logic mixed up with my filter logic. Anyhow, this  works

```
var breweryFilter=[
    "all",
    ["in", "stateNam", 'Utah','Texas','Florida'],
    ["in", "breweryType", 'Irish','American']
]
map.setFilter('breweriesLayer',breweryFilter)
```