# Mapbox expression to return greater of two values

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm looking to plot the equivalent of the SQL query

```sql
SELECT column_3
FROM my_object
WHERE map_layer is not null
AND column_1 > column_2;
```

Using this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313134/matching-multiple-properties-in-mapbox-gl-js-filter) I can see where the expression should go (in the filter) and that I can combine multiple filters but not how to compare values.

Which gives me

```js
"source-layer": "my_object",
        "filter": ['all',["==", ["typeof", ["get", "col_3"]], "string"],[another expression here]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would interpret *'greater of two values'* as the (PG) SQL equivalent of

```
SELECT GREATEST(column_1, column_2)
...
```

However, the query you posted would simply translate to

```
"filter": [">", ["get", "column_1"], ["get", "column_2"]]
```

or

```
"filter": [
  "all", 
  ["!=", ["get", "map_layer"], "<NULL_VALUE>"],
  [">", ["get", "column_1"], ["get", "column_2"]
]
```

> *filter for (show only) all features where ["map_layer" is not "NULL_VALUE" and] "column_1" is greater than "column_2"*

Note that you will need to fill in `"<NULL_VALUE>"` with the actual value that you get returned (e.g. `""` for an empty string);

Comment: Thank you for the pointer this got me to what I needed, I had to explicitly get col3 as it styling is categorical `"filter": ["all",["==", ["typeof", ["get", "col_3"]], "string"],[">",["get","column_1"],["get","column_2"]]],`

Comment: Just seen your edit, much more elegant than the above! Also thanks for raising awareness of PG `GREATEST`